# Files did not merge properly in TFS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I had branched one of my projects few months back and merged it back today. It said it merged around 460 files but I don't see any of my changes in the original project. I also added few new files to the branched project which got merged but my other code changes did not. Any idea how can I fix this?

When I try to merge now, it says both the files are identical but I can see the difference when I open the files next to each other. I have too many changes to go through each file individually.

Thanks in advance.

Mithil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason TFS couldn't recognize the difference in my files. I had to manually go into each file and copy the changes to the original file. Not a very pleasant experience.

Answer (score 2):

Download TFS Powertools and run tf merge and do a /force.  This happens when the cached version is incorrect.

[Merge Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

An example would be:

c:\MyProject>tf merge /version:C100 branch1 branch2 /recursive /force

Comment: Ran the tf merge through VS Command prompt. Still says "There are no changes to merger"

Comment: When you did the merge back to your main branch did you checkin the merge?  TFS will merge the files for you but you still have to check in the merged files.

Comment: If you ran TF Merge /force and you branched up from a dev branch to a main branch and you ran /recursive it will merge the data.  If it says "there are no changes to merge" then there are no changes to merge.  /force ignores all previous change history.